# can't install pyinstaller at ubuntu

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using python2 and having trouble installing pyinstaller. Here's what I've tried:

```
root@host:~/setup# pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/96/21ba3619647bac2b34b4996b2dbbea8e74a703767ce24192899d9153c058/pyinstaller-4.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6zdWWq/pyinstaller/setup.py", line 63
        file=sys.stderr)
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6zdWWq/pyinstaller/
```

Comment: Pyinstaller 4 doesn't support Python 2.

Comment: thx :) how to choose version which i want to install?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pip+choose+version+to+install

Comment: Try calling it as `pip3` rather than just `pip`

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding, Pyinstaller v4.0 does not support Python 2 which is what I assume is being downloaded when you use `pip install pyinstaller`.

Solution:

1. Visit [Pyinstaller Release History](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/3.0/#history) to view the version you would like to install (all versions from Python v3.6 down to v3.0 support Python 2)
2. Install the Pyinstaller version of your choice using: `pip install pyinstaller==3.5` this should work for you!

Images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]