# After generating .exe from .py file following error occurred while running .exe file from dist folder

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyinstaller, plotly-dash, py2exe

I am new to python and made an app in dash-plotly. The script/app in running as required in .py or ipynb format. I covert this app.py file to .exe by following instruction given in below link:

[Converting .py to .exe with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089420/converting-py-to-exe-with-anaconda)

.exe was made in dist folder. I tried running it by double clicking the .exe

But error was displayed in .exe and I'v attached the screenshot of the error message.

[Error while running .exe from dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvxQU.jpg)

Kindly find the below github link of app.py:

https://github.com/varunluniya/Defect_analysis