# How to create an executable for an application created using Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, exe, pyinstaller

I have a Python script that uses TensorFlow and Keras through Anaconda, and I want to package it as an executable. The problem is that when I use pyinstaller, the executable is created, but when I try to run it, the terminal window opens for a split second and then closes.

I tried doing the same thing through the `conda` command prompt, but the same thing happens. I was wondering if anyone knew the fix, or if there is any way to package the environment and Python script so it doesn't need a compiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting .py to .exe with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089420/converting-py-to-exe-with-anaconda)